# Lein console (like sbt)

Tags: clojure, leiningen

Is there some built-in functionality or plugin to lein to get a *lein console*, so for example one could test without waiting every time for JVM to start up.

```
$ lein console
>>> test
...
>>> test
...
>>> jar
```

*Note:* I'd like to trigger test runs myself, not e.g. by watching source files. That's why I'd like to have a lein console.

*Clarification:* I'm not looking for `lein repl`. I'd like to have a console where I could run lein task commands.

Comment: are you looking for `lein repl`?

Comment: @cfrick no, lein repl starts *clojure repl*. I'd like a console where I could run  lein task commands.

Comment: lein is a clojure program, and its tasks can be run in a repl if you load the lein libs

Comment: @noisesmith If you start up a REPL inside a project, the Leiningen namespaces will not be available (.e.g `leiningen.core.main`), so you'd have to explicitly include them in the project's (dev) dependencies which does not seem clean to me.

Comment: @noisesmith Additionally, project-dependent Leiningen tasks are functions that take a project map as their first parameter to know the context they are running in - and it can be quite hard to get one. (I mean, just _try_ to generate a JAR from the REPL.) In conclusion: while it is possible to use Leiningen from the REPL it's neither easy nor convenient.

Comment: "just try to generate a jar" https://www.refheap.com/96856

Comment: @noisesmith, won't say that has good user experience. I'd appreciate something more convenient. Someone have to package that as a lein plugin.

Comment: @noisesmith  I didn't want to sound condescending. It's a nice proof-of-concept but I feel at the least the "not convenient" part of my comment still stands.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to have a look at [grenchman](https://github.com/technomancy/grenchman). While it's not a Leiningen console it at least enables reusing of an existing REPL session. From what I gather, usage is as follows:

1. Move somewhere that is not inside a project and call:

   ```
   $ lein repl :headless
   ```
2. Within your project directory, use:

   ```
   $ grench lein <task> <options>
   ```

Tasks will be run inside the already spun up Leiningen JVM and the startup overhead should disappear.

Building grenchman seems to be tedious, though, and it is recommended to use one of the [precompiled binaries](http://leiningen.org/grench.html#download) (**BUT** they are currently [not available](https://github.com/technomancy/grenchman/issues/30)).

And finally, that page also states:

> Grenchman is still very new and may not be fully reliable.

So, good luck, I guess?

Comment: Sadly it appears the Grenchman binary downloads have gone away :( I get permission denied for all of them.

Comment: Oh no. Seems to be a [known issue](https://github.com/technomancy/grenchman/issues/30) ...

Answer (score 1):

Older versions of leiningen used to include `lein interactive`, which behaved much like the feature you are asking for: it opened a shell into which you could type `test` and have it run `lein test` from the already-running lein jvm, and so on. This feature was removed in the transition to lein 2.0, I think, and although I don't know why I suspect there was a good reason. Maybe try asking in #leiningen on freenode?

Answer (score 0):

One option is to run a repl from `leiningen`'s own jar file.

```
$ java -cp ~/.lein/self-installs/leiningen-2.5.0-standalone.jar clojure.main
Clojure 1.6.0
user=> (require '[leiningen.core.project :as project] '[leiningen.test :as test])
nil
user=> (def prj (project/read))
#'user/prj
user=> (test/test prj)

lein test org.noisesmith.orsos.load-test

Ran 3 tests containing 3 assertions.
0 failures, 0 errors.
nil
user=> (require '[leiningen.jar :as jar])
nil
user=> (jar/jar prj 'org.noisesmith.orsos)
Compiling org.noisesmith.orsos
Created /media/justin/806084F16084EEEA/clojure/orsos/target/orsos-0.1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
{[:extension "jar"] "/media/justin/806084F16084EEEA/clojure/orsos/target/orsos-0.1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar"}
user=>
```

As a baseline, this can run lein tasks without having to restart lein every time. If you also use `rlwrap` or use `nrepl` it becomes a bit more usable. As far as I know there is no user friendly tooling around this (though there easily could be).

If you wish to use tasks from lein plugins those can be added to the `-cp` arg.